# Android - Intent that open widget context menu

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-contextmenu

in my application I want that when a user click a button the application closes itself and automatically opens the add new widget context Menu.
I'm making this:

```
if (viewId == R.id.bt_homeScreen) {
        finish();
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.homeClientAlert), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The problem whith this code is that I only go to the phone Home screen:

[image: http://cdn.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/rc33-google-voice-search-for-android-on-home-screen.jpg]
<sub>(source: [androidtapp.com](http://cdn.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/rc33-google-voice-search-for-android-on-home-screen.jpg))</sub>

I want that when I launch the Intent it goes to the Home screen and open the widget context menu:

[image: http://www.taosoftware.co.jp/en/android/calendarwidget/img/choosewidget.png]
<sub>(source: [taosoftware.co.jp](http://www.taosoftware.co.jp/en/android/calendarwidget/img/choosewidget.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Commonsware's answer to this question: [Add widget to homescreen from Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449884/add-widget-to-homescreen-from-android-application)

You will be able to show the widget selection menu but you won't be able to process that selection in a normal app. The application that makes use of an appwidget selection must implement an AppWidgetHost. Home screen apps fall into this category, no normal apps.