# Place app widget on homescreen out of an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-activity

I know that it's not possible to place an app widget programatically on the homescreen - the user has to do it by himself. But is there a way, to let the user create an app widget without having to go to the "widgets-tab" and choosing it from the list of all available widgets?

My idea is to have a `Button` in my `Activity`, which provides some kind of shortcut to that list . This way the user still would create it by himself, but he wouldn't have to leave the app. Is there an `Intent` I could use in combination with `startActivityForResult()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at CommonsWare answer here:

[Add widget to homescreen from Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449884/add-widget-to-homescreen-from-android-application)

You can bring the list up put you are unable to select a widget and install it for that your app must be an appWidgetHost

Answer (score 0):

In Android O, its possible to pin app widget programmatically. Just watch at example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655507/4826038)

Also check out Google official [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655507/4826038)